# best way to redirect a link to other domain (conditional)?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, redirect

We provide a link (example http://indiapriceinfo.in/getbeststore?mobile_id=76340 ) which redirects user to the online store which is selling it at best price (so the redirection link will lead you to different store on different days).
We use these kind of links on multiple domains with 302 redirection. But they all redirect using indiapriceinfo.in, like the above.

Is this bad for SEO? If it is then whats the best pratice to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 302 redirect is exactly what you should be doing since the redirects are temporary. The fact that the links all point to pages on the same domain is irrelvant as the links are judged on a per page basis, not per site. So indiapriceinfo.in won't gain anything as a domain SEO wise from these links.